# Trouble with bulk data load to Elastic via curl

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an index from a json file.

The json file looks like:

```
{"index": {"_id": "1"}}
{"description": "\n\n\nbunches of text with embedded \n newlines.\n\n\n"}
{"index": {"_id": "10"}}
{"description": "more text","abstract":"less text"}
```

etc...
(the indices are sorted in glob order, which is why 10 is after 1 here)

I am trying to insert this into an existing index (containing no docs) using:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "localhost:9200/rktest1/_doc/_bulk?pretty&refresh" --data-binary "@myfile.json"; echo
```

But echo is not echoing anything, and my index is not being updated

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'                     
health status index   uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   rktest1 4gcNmk8ZSUW-n_0Jc4cnMA   5   1          0            0      1.1kb          1.1kb
```

This is pretty much copied out of the elastic documentation, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  I'd appreciate help with this particular case, but I'd also love to know if there is an argument I can send to get more feedback about what's going on with that POST to help me debug for myself?

Comment: can you run your curl with `-s -v`? What do you get? Also make sure that your `myfile.json` file has a new line as the last line

Comment: `* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9200 (#0)
> POST /rktest1/_doc/_bulk?pretty&refresh HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:9200
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 341473811
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
< content-length: 0
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
* Closing connection 0`

Comment: I assume this is the problem: `413 Request Entity Too Large` -- but perhaps that should be a separate question

Comment: The server’s balking at a 341MB POST payload. Try batching your insertion in smaller chunks.